# how to access property when laravel relationname camelcase

Tags: laravel, relation

I have a problem about laravel relation name when I use the relation name with camelcase. I can't access the relation property.

My laravel version is 5.4.

The code list:

Post Model code:

```
namespace App;

use App\Api\Entities\BaseModel;

class Post extends BaseModel
{

    public $table = 'posts';

    public function community()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Communities::class, 'community_id', 'id');
    }

    public function communityInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Communities::class, 'community_id', 'id');
    }

    public function community_info()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Communities::class, 'community_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

The controller code:

```
$post = Post::with('community_info')->find(1);
dd($post->community_info);  // success 

==========================

$post = Post::with('communityInfo')->find(1);
dd($post->communityInfo);  // return null

==========================

$post = Post::with('community')->find(1);
dd($post->community);  // success

==========================

$post = Post::with('communityInfo')->find(1);
dd($post->community_info);  // return null

==========================

$post = Post::with('communityInfo')->find(1);
dd($post->getRelation('communityInfo')); // success
```

Above, which way is correct for get the camelcase？ can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: what exact version of Laravel?

Comment: my laravel version is 5.4

Comment: can you update your question to include the code of `Model Post`?

Comment: Ok, I hava add the code of Model Post! Thanks!

Comment: Could you send the query value of each test?
smthing like `Post::with('communityInfo')->toSql()`